# A webpage that I've not made is showing up in my google analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics, server

I was checking my Google analytics and had a spike in traffic. On further investigation, it was all to a page at http://mikehigginswebdesign.com/h/25742.html which I've never created. I tried logging in to the file manager and via FTP do delete the /h directory but it doesn't show up anywhere at all.

I don't understand how this web page could exist without me creating it or why all of a sudden there is a load of traffic to it. Anyone know how I can somehow get rid of this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the non-existence of the page, it's likely this is a case of referrer spam. This page isn't listed in Google Search Results and is probably an invented URL.

There are various types of Analytics Spam but check the source of the clicks. They often make repeated requests using a fake referrer URL to the site they want to promote.

Comment: If you follow the URL you will see that the page does in fact exist - which means that this is not a problem with Google Analytics.

Comment: You can add any page title and it will revert to this unstyled page. This page has not specifically been created. If you visit this link http://mikehigginswebdesign.com/h/ThisIsAMadeUpURL.html it will take you to the same page.